All strips are greyed out

I don't know which one (NLA strip) is selected. Even if I click on a strip, it is not highlighted


your tracks are muted and locked but it doesn't explain why you can't click on the strip, could you please share your file? Remove all the useless objects... https://blend-exchange.com/

I don't know why too, that's why I asked

How do I send you the file?

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

I've added the file, kindly check it out

it works for me, have you tried another Blender version? https://i.postimg.cc/wBPNrmhN/anim.gif

My bad, I meant the side bar. Something like this https://i.postimg.cc/DZ58Cxy3/Snipaste-2024-11-12-18-41-00.png

Hello? Did it also work for you?

Yes it works for me

Any idea what's wrong then? Could it be my user preference settings??

That's weird, I have no idea   :((

No worries, I figured it out. Thanks for your help.


The issue was the theme I was using (I use maya theme just because I like the gradient falloff in the viewport background). One I switched it back to Blender Dark (the default theme) the issue was fixed.
In case you still want that gradient color for your viewport, simply go to the theme drop-down menus, click "3d viewport", then "theme space", select "linear gradient" and edit the colors as you wish.
